# Using Phpunit/ Why phpunit removes all data in my database

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I'm trying to test my functions but everytime I try to run phpunit, it will delete all the records in my tables.  I already setup my phpunit.xml file, to just in my test database, I just followed everything in the docs, do I have to setup a sqlite inmy machine, since I don't have that ? or what ? I only have laragon installed and phpmyadmin.

phpunit.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
   backupStaticAttributes="false"
   bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
   colors="true"
   convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
   convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
   convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
   processIsolation="false"
   stopOnFailure="false">
   <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Feature">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
    </testsuite>

    <testsuite name="Unit">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
<filter>
    <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/> 
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
</php>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: Your MySQL db is cleaned? Because PHPunit doesn't delete anything, it's a testing framework which runs test classes located at the `testsuites`. The test classes can perform code which can touch a database. But in your case Laravel will be booted on test class creation and that will creates a new database in memory. The database will be removed from memory after the test class is run.

Comment: I used the RefreshDatabase trait,but I already did added those in my phpunit.xml why do I still encounter that same operation ? when phpunit.xml is already edited..

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use the `DatabaseMigrations` trait in your test classes. Eg.

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class SomeTest extends TestCase
{
     use DatabaseMigrations;
     use RegreshDatabase;

   /**
    * A basic test example.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function testSomething()
    {
        //some code
    }
        
}
```

This migrates your data on setup, and then registers a direction to roll back the migrations when the application is torn down at the end of the test.

Comment: what does this mean sir ?

Comment: To answer your question, it migrates your data on setup, and then registers a direction to roll back the migrations when the application is torn down at the end of the test.

Comment: Hey man, didn't work out for me, this is much worse because it deleted all my tables in my database, SHAM

Comment: Try run php artisan config:clear and php artisan cache:clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186513/discussion-between-peter-sowah-and-thebast).